# Sorted subset of a list with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have an domain object holding a list containing many items. The items order is maintained by hibernate (@OrderColumn). Furthermore I have double checked that the order column is correctly set.

Since the list can be very long I've tried to fetch the items like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Select d.list From DomainObject d where d.key = :key");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);
query.list();
```

Unfortunately the returned list is not ordered. Currently the only way for me to get a ordered list back is modifying my query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Select d From DomainObject d where d.key = :key");
query.uniqueResult();
```

It seems like hibernate is doing the item ordering only when they are within the domain object.

Since the later solution can have quite a high memory impact I'd like to know if there is a way to make hibernate return an orderd subset of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria can be used like below.
Please change the following code as per your requirements:

```
@Override
    public List<Certification> loadAll() {
        Criteria criteria = template.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Certification.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("certificationAbbr"),"certificationAbbr")
                .add(Projections.property("certificationDesc"),"certificationDesc"))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("certificationAbbr"))
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Certification.class));
        return criteria.list();
    }
```